# Xamarin Portable config file using PCLAppConfig

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to put a config file in the PCL portion of my IOS/Android app.

The documentation at: https://github.com/mrbrl/PCLAppConfig
suggests:

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings = new ConfigurationManager(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DemoApp.App.config")).GetAppSettings;
```

I expect DemoApp is the assembly name of their sample app so I have:

using PCLAppConfig;

```
namespace LYG
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            Assembly assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings = new ConfigurationManager(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("LYG.App.config")).AppSettings;
        }
...
    }    
}
```

I get the following compile error:

/Users/greg/Projects/LYG/LYG/LYG.cs(122,122): Error CS1061: Type `PCLAppConfig.ConfigurationManager' does not contain a definition for`GetAppSettings' and no extension method `GetAppSettings' of type`PCLAppConfig.ConfigurationManager' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061) (LYG)

This is my packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="PCLAppConfig" version="0.3.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="PCLStorage" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
</packages>
```

I also tried with parentheses:

```
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings = new ConfigurationManager(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("LYG.App.config")).AppSettings();
```

Why can't the GetAppSettings be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the PCLAppConfig nuget package to your PCL and platforms projects.

Then I take you are trying to use the resource based app.config;
I just updated the documentation to reflect the last version update.

then use:

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
ConfigurationManager.Initialise(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DemoApp.App.config"));
```

in doubt, check the demo project on github : https://github.com/mrbrl/PCLAppConfig/tree/master/src/DemoApp